# Move to backward and forward on button click in uiwebview

Tags: ios

hi i want to move to next page of html file on next button click and previous button click.

```
NSString *htmlPath   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"opening" ofType:@"html"];
NSData *htmlData     = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath];
NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, i have created two buttons next and previous. i also give a page number for every page but i can't move  by the page number. so please give me some logic for this.

Comment: So you want to go to next and previous page like the next and previous button functionality of web-browser, am I correct ?

Comment: i have uiwebview and load a html file on it. now i want to move on next and previous page on button click accordingly.

Comment: For going to previous page you can use `[self.webView goBack];` for going to next page you need to write custom logic. (There is  `[self.webView goForward];`, but you can't use it in this scenario)

Comment: yes sir i know i can't use this logic in it, because i am performing action with html content. can u help me with any logic for this.

Comment: If you know the next html file names, you can keep those in an array and using an index variable you can load the page.

Comment: @SandeepChaudhary thanks for asking this important question.it helps me so much

Answer (score 2):

To go `Forward`, `Backward` you just need to call these default `UIWebview` methods

```
-(IBAction)goBackAction{
    if(self.webView.canGoBack){
      [self.webView goBack];
    }
}

-(IBAction)goForwardAction{
    if(self.webView.canGoForward){
      [self.webView goForward];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.